# Рандомные картинки

Tags: случайные-числа

Я работаю учителем английского, у нас в классе установлен большой смарт ТВ, и на данный момент мы с детьми проходим цифры.
Я хочу написать небольшой скрипт или программу, чтобы можно было нажимать на изображение и появлялись рандом цифры от 1 до 10, потом опять нажимаешь на текущую цифру и появляется рандомная от 1 до 10, и так снова.
Хочу сделать свой урок интереснее, чтобы дети могли сами тыкать и называть цифру.
На тв установлена Windows 7, желательно, чтобы это можно было сделать в пакете Microsoft Office (word, excel, power point хорошо знаю), но если кто-то натыкался на видео или урок в интернете с чем-то подобным можете просто дать ссылку. Я разберусь. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Smart TV на Windows 7? Или просто телевизор подключен как монитор к компьютеру?

Comment: Именно smart TV

Comment: Если у вас там имеется браузер, то можно наверное написать простенький html-файл, который позволит вам осуществить задуманное

Comment: Да, конечно, браузер есть, стоит полноценная винда

Comment: Кстати, хорошая идея, я что-то про браузер совсем забыла

Comment: Уточните вопрос, на smart TV, судя по [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_smart_TV_platforms_and_middleware_software), Windows никогда не ставился. У вас скорре всего подключение как монитор.

Comment: Как вариант можете посмотреть этот пример - https://learn.javascript.ru/task/random-int-min-max + почитать про клики, обновление элементов на странице (https://learn.javascript.ru/), а также как красиво оформить все это хозяйство (http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/bazovyy-sintaksis-css)

Comment: О_о серьезно стоит огромный телек, метр длина точно, стоит, наверное, дороже, чем я. Я могу завтра фотку скинуть и модель посмотреть, потому что с работы уже ушла

Comment: @Helen наверняка вы просто не так поняли, как там всё работает. Может быть это и не "телек" вовсе, а моноблок. Иначе было бы интересно узнать модель.

Comment: Не исключено, завтра напишу модель, самой теперь интересно

Answer (score 3):

1. Мне кажется вам нужно почитать про [ms visual basic for applications](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), который позволит внести некоторые элементы программирование в пакет **MS Office** и тогда вы сможете запускать презентацию только с кликом, после которого и будет меняться цифра.
2. Как верно заметил **Sergey Glazirin** в комментариях про браузер, проще и быстрей будет написать `html` страничку, благодаря `JavaScript` вы сможете генерировать рандомные числа и повесите событие на кнопку, а с помощью `css` всё это дело красиво оформите.

Comment: Да, я вот тоже об этом подумала, я невеликий программист, но, думаю, это должно получиться)